# Pandas : How can I find missing data which is existing in only one data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

```
In [4]: chois_df.head()
Out[4]:
         word  doc        tf
0      reason   10  0.571429
1  moderately   10  0.571429
2         bad   10  0.642857
3   coherence   10  0.571429
4  inviolable   10  0.571429

In [6]: test_df.head()
Out[6]:
         word  doc        tf
0      reason   10  0.571429
1  moderately   10  0.571429
2         bad   10  0.642857
3   coherence   10  0.571429
4  inviolable   10  0.571429

In [2]: chois_df.count()
Out[2]:
word    260800
doc     260801
tf      260801
dtype: int64

In [3]: test_df.count()
Out[3]:
word    260742
doc     260743
tf      260743
dtype: int64
```

As you can see above, `chois_df` has more `word` than `test_df`.

How can I find which word are redundant in `chois_df`?

Since length of data frame are different, it's kinda difficult to compare them.

Need your advices, Thanks.

Comment: its hard to understand what you want. what do you mean by redundant? higher frequency count?

Comment: Sorry for my poor explanation. As you can see the codes, `chois_df` has more data than `test_df` by 58, right? I want to know these 58 data as data frame

Answer (score 1):

what about simply

```
all = chois_df.merge(test_df, how = 'left', on = ['word', 'doc'], indicator = True)
all[all._merge == 'left_only']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `set`

```
set(chois_df.word).difference(test_df.word)
```

This will get the set of words in `chois_df` that is not in `test_df`

Comment: yeah nice one my friend

Answer (score 0):

## This will create a new dataframe with the difference between chois_df and test_df.

newdf = test_df[~test_df.isin(chois_df)]

## You can then drop all the extra NANS

newdf = newdf.dropna()